# css3 slide up, jerky animation of the content under it

Tags: css

Following a book's code for slide up/down animation using anglularjs here is the example code: http://jsfiddle.net/bx01muha/2/

here is the css code:

```
.container {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.slide-tile {
    transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    width:300px;    
    text-align:center;
    border: 1px solid black;
    transform: translateY(0);
}
.slide-tile.ng-hide {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
}
```

The problem is when the content is slide up/down the content under it moved up/down with a jerk. How to fix a css3 slide up/down so that the content under it also moves smoothly?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use simple JavaScript/jQuery?

Here's my solution: http://codepen.io/n3ptun3/pen/EVJzPv/

It fixes the "jerky" issue, although it doesn't use Angular. Hope this helps!

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <div>
    <button>
      Toggle Visibility
    </button>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="slide slide-tile">
        Slide me up and down! lets see whats going on...
      </div>            
    </div>
    <h1 class="slide">Jerky</h1>
  </div>   
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slide-tile {
  transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  width:300px;    
  text-align:center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.hide {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}

h1 {
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

**JavaScript/jQuery**

```
$(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $(".slide").toggleClass("hide");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at your example, but did not see any jerkiness that you were referring to. I have had this symptom many a time however, in various sites I have built.

I have often found that depending on which device I am viewing my site on, which browser I'm using, and what else is going on, CSS3 animations can appear jerky.

### Possible Causes

#### Browser/Hardware Performance

Most web browsers are fine for common transitions and animations. Some however, freak out and start jerking when animating either a large amount of screen real estate or elements.

CSS doesn't seem to have caught up to JavaScript for animations in some performance aspects **yet**.

#### Animation Speed

Animation speed can be a factor in both the actual animation speed (directly affects jerkiness), and browser performance.

If its too slow, it will look jerky. The speed of your animation looks perfect however, and I didn't experience any issues.

#### JavaScript

If JavaScript is also trying to perform animations on the same element as the CSS, I have seen this make animation on the element jerky as JS and CSS fight over who is doing the animating.

### Possible Solutions

- Ensure you aren't running too many CSS animations on-screen at the same time.
- Try viewing the animation on a different device.
- If the element is being animated by JavaScript as well, try and change it so that only the CSS (or JS if pref) is doing the animation.